# change css of first child element with class

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to write javascript code to change the css display property of a the first div after the element user clicked on, which has the class `toggle-placement` .
my code creates a page using a loop. the loop generates this piece of code every time:

```
<h3 class="placementName" onclick="showPlacement()" title="<?php echo $placement->getId() ?>"> Placement: <?php echo $placement->getName() ?></h3>
<div class="toggle-placement">
```

the `toggle-placement` initialized with `display:none` and i want to show each div after clicking the `<h3>` above it.
how can i get the div right after the header and change its css ? thx

Comment: `$('h3.placementName').click(function() { $(this).next('.toggle-placement').show(); })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `jQuery`, @haim770, provide best answer :

```
$('h3.placementName').click(
   function() { 
      $(this).next('.toggle-placement').show(); 
   }
)
```

But with css i don't think it is possible. you must have to use jquery for what you are looking for.

May be it help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can easiest make your action with jQuery:

```
$('.placementName').click( // when you click on a '.placementName' class element.
    function() {
        $(this).next('.toggle-placement').show(); // show() == display:block;
});
```

You have the documentation of the next()'s selector here => https://api.jquery.com/next/

Just an edit :

With jQuery:

```
$('.placementName').
```

is faster than :

```
$('h3.placementName').
```

If you using the class "placementName" just on the < h3 > element, you can just use the " $('.placementName'). " performance test => http://jsperf.com/jquery-selector-test

Answer (score 0):

Well it´s easier if you do the following:

In your CSS create a class called hide:

```
.hide{
  display:none;
}
```

Then in your Javascript do the following:

```
$('.placementName').on('click', function() {
    $(this).next('.toggle-placement').toggleClass('hide'); 
});
```